# Pagination and how to return all possible options together with database search results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a database containing over 5 million rows.

**Question 1.**

At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars
```

Count total rows to be returned. The above example is very basic. Queries do get more complex with WHERE clause.

I'm showing 50 rows per page. Using PHP I count total pages and offset based on current page retrieved from PHP $_GET. This gets passed to the following query:

```
SELECT ID FROM cars ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $offset, 50
```

I fetch all IDs of rows to be displayed in current page put them in a single string.

```
$ID_list = implode( ',', array_column( $mysqli_fetch, 'ID' ) );
```

This then gets passed to final query.

```
SELECT ID, make, model, year, price FROM cars WHERE ID IN ($ID_list)
```

Performance wise I find that passing IDs to third query is up to 8 times faster than just selecting all required columns in second query.

What is the most efficient way to paginate results while displaying total rows count and page numbers. While OFFSET, LIMIT pagination is not efficient, using seek method is not possible to display page numbers. Is there an alternative method? Maybe I should look into technologies other than MySQLi?

**Question 2.**

What is the best approach in displaying all possible search results of returned data?

https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?advertClassification=standard&postcode=B4%206TB&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&advertising-location=at_cars&is-quick-search=TRUE&page=1

The search in the website above starts with no filters applied. Now I can click on for example, Make and it shows a number of possible results next to car brand name. Same goes for every other option. How is this achieved?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site works differently from other sites. You don't ask for "help" here in the form of a free-form discussion. A question must be **single** and well-formed. Right now the question doesn't seem very well thought: it is highly unlikely that running two queries that select the same set of rows will be faster than selecting this set of rows in one query. You have to focus on this very confusion only, providing as much details as possible.

Comment: Personally, I, Do not think you can see a difference in execution time with a query of 50 rows of data. As in your queries. You **_may_** have a difference in time of presentation of your data. Look somewhere at `PHP` level. That is my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1's issues and solution is discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

That strongly recommends "remember where you left off" instead of `OFFSET`, providing a significant performance improvement. It gets rid of `$ID_list` and lets you do the two `SELECTs` as one (which is another performance benefit).  (Your 8x improvement was due the *combination* of selecting multiple columns and skipping over rows (`OFFSET`).)

Question 2 is more difficult since you want to do multiple counts.  Try using`GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` to get all the counts in a single query.  The risk is that this might involve so much data (eg, all 5M rows) that it takes "too long".  In the few cases where a "covering" index is available, it might not be "too long".

You *could* do big group-bys every night -- counts by make and no filtering, counts by model-year and no filtering, etc.  Store those in a table for quickly fetching.  Once you add filtering, the complexity makes this impractical.  Note: doing such a nightly tally implies that you analyze the user's request in order to tailor the `SELECT`.

Even the count-how-many-row-we-are-about-to-page-through (of Question 1) may be too costly.

See this for how to segregate the "common" attributes from the "rare" ones:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav .  That leads to having several composite queries of 2-3 columns in order to handle *most* of the `SELECT` from people with random filtering criteria.

Keep the table size down by using minimal datatypes.  Model_year could use a 2-byte `YEAR` datatype.  An auto_inc for 5M cars could use a 3-byte `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (16M limit).

Normalization (replacing a long string with a short id) saves space, but is likely to cost too much when the queries filter on multiple criteria.  Eg: `make = 'Ford' AND model = 'F150'`.

`AND` is relatively easy to optimize in a `WHERE` clause; `IN` is worse and `OR` is even worse.  For some of the `IN` and `OR` cases, you may need to resort to `UNION` to rid of such.  Example:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE make = 'BMW' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE make = 'Audi' )
```

There will be a number of other cases where you really need to "construct" the query in your app code, not simply hope that MySQL can do something optimal.

The above `UNION` does not allow for pagination; see my links on how to deal with such.